# How long will it take for my credit score to reflect my name having been taken off a mortgage?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

As part of divorce settlement (January 2011) my ex was required to remove me from our Mortgage and Home Equity Loan ($600,000). For 23 years we made timely payments, so there was no BAD DEBT - just debt.

My problem is that it took him 2.8 years, and in that time my income to debt ratio was overwhelming. I was denied the most simple credit applications. During that period I paid any and all debts that I personally incurred both in full, and on time.

Now that I am off, how long will it take for Equifax, Transunion and Experion to reflect the change?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience looking at [CreditKarma](http://www.CreditKarma.com) things like this happen quickly. Things like credit utilization are a real time item, if you check your score a few days after the big credit card bill hits, you'll see high utilization.

To be specific, the score will reflect it within a few days of the bank properly reporting it. That's the real delay.